# How to pass an object's properties as the locals to an include in Jade?

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine, pug

I'd like to pass an object inside a loop as follows;

**data structure:**

```
things = [
      {
          title: 'foo'
        , description: 'bar'
      }
    , {
          title: 'baz'
        , description: 'bam'
      }
];
```

**index.jade:**

```
- for thing in things
    include things-template
```

In the above format, I'd like to be able to specify a parameter of some sort as "locals" for that include.

**things-template.jade:**

```
li
  h3 #{title}
  p #{description}
```

Is this possible, or do I need to assign it to another variable and reference it inside my "thing-template"?

Comment: I would highly recommend that you adopt the syntax mandated by JSLint...

Comment: What specifically, +Ates Goral?

Comment: I'm just saying that the placement of your braces and commas is not very conventional. If you ever think of adopting a different style, I would recommend sticking to the one mandated by Crockford (or JSLint). You'll often see that style being used in OSS projects. It's also very similar to the Sun Java style. Using a conventional style helps with collaborating with other people...

Comment: @Martindale, I really want this feature as well, but I don't believe it is coming... :(

Answer (score 3):

As the newest jade version (0.27.4)
You can pass object reference as the same name of template

```
for thing in things
  include thing
```

will automatic include ./thing.jade with thing as object
in thing.jade:

```
li
  h3 #{thing.title}
  p #{thing.description}
```

Comment: The problem is that things-template.jade is useful on its own.  By specifying "thing.title" instead of just "title" you need to change the locals passed when rendering it on its own.

Comment: Does not work for me. I get an error saying `no such file ... thing template`. In my case `thing` should be a string path to a template. Instead jade thinks the template itself is called `thing`.

Answer (score -3):

As you want to include existing templates, I guess that you don't have so many. Why don't you simply use à jade `case` block ?

```
html
    body
        for thing in things
            case things-template
                when "simple"
                    include simple
                when "complexe"
                    include complexe
                default
                    include simple
```